# How do I simplify a $\cos$ and $\sin$ equation

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic

Simplify :
$$\cos(u-v)\sin v + \sin(u-v)\cos v$$

I have tried doing this:
$$\sin[v \cos(u-v) + (\cos v(u-v)]
= \sin[\cos v(u-v) + \cos v(u-v)]$$

But then I'm stuck here...

Comment: What you wrote as your attempt doesn't make sense. How did you get from the problem statement to $\sin[\cos v(u-v) + \cos v(u-v)],$ for example?

Comment: You certainly can't move the $v$ about in the way you have - what rules do you think you are applying? $\cos (a+b)=\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b; \sin (a+b) = \sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b$ are the ones I remember, and take care with signs if I'm subtracting. There are different ways to go.

Comment: Although you now have an answer, I worry that you will keep getting lost because you don't understand questions like this. It seems as if you never received the information that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are functions and that the rules you learned for manipulating expressions like $Ax+By$ (where $A$ and $B$ are numbers) simply do not apply to expressions like $\sin x + \cos y.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that 
$$\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b).$$
Now let $a=u-v$ and $b=v$. What is the simplified formula?

Answer (score 3):

As $\sin(a+b) = \sin a \cos b + \sin b \cos a $, your expression is equal to:

$$ \sin ((u-v)+v) = \sin u$$